# logarithmic big O proof

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

I am asked to prove that
     $log^{log n}log n$ = O($2^{\sqrt n})$
I've tried so much and don't have any idea to solve it please help 
thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but $\log(n)=\mathcal O(\sqrt n)$

Comment: Is that $(\log(\log(n)))^{\log(n)}$? If not, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(n)=\log^{\log(n)}\log(n)$$

$$\log[f(n)]=\log(n)\log[\log(\log(n))]$$

and for $n>100$.

$$<\sqrt n$$

Thus, $\log[f(n)]=\mathcal O(\sqrt n)\implies f(n)=\mathcal O(a^{\sqrt n})$